# Error 1064 (42000): error in your SQL syntax ... near ' '

Tags: python, sql, mariadb, mysql-error-1064

I'm stuck since a couple days and tried most of the answer given to similar questions on this site.

Before starting I'd like to point out that I am working via ssh and can only edit the code via nano (not my choice...)

My problem is the following:

I am using MariaDB to store the raspberry pi CPU temperature along a camera temperature to plot the temperature evolution. I have an error when trying to insert the values in the data base.

I have the following table in cpu_tempDB

```
MariaDB [cpu_tempDB]> show columns from CPU_TEMP_TABLE;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| ID          | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| CPU_TEMP    | decimal(6,2) | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| CREATED     | timestamp    | NO   |     | current_timestamp() |                |
| CAMERA_TEMP | decimal(6,2) | NO   |     | 0.00                |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

In my python code I use the following functions:

```
from gpiozero import CPUTemperature
import mysql.connector as mariadb

# get CPU temperature in Celsius
cpu = CPUTemperature()
cpu_temp = cpu.temperature

# get Camera temperature in Celsius
tempfile = open("/home/pi/allsky/temperature.txt","r")
cam_temp = tempfile.read().rstrip()

# make a new mariaDB entry and retrieve old values
try:
   # open connection
   mariadb_connection = mariadb.connect(host= "localhost", user="pi", password="--Sensored--", database="cpu_tempDB")
   cursor = mariadb_connection.cursor()
   # upload
   sql = "insert into CPU_TEMP_TABLE (CPU_TEMP, CAMERA_TEMP) values (%s, %s)"
   args = cpu_temp, float(cam_temp)
   cursor.execute(sql,args)
   mariadb_connection.commit()
   # fetch
   cursor.execute("select * from CPU_TEMP_TABLE where CPU_TEMP_TABLE.CREATED > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY")
   records = cursor.fetchall()
except mariadb.Error as e:
   print("Error writing cpu temp to mariaDB:",e)
finally:
   mariadb_connection.close()
   cursor.close()
# store data in lists
time_list = []
cpu_temp_list = []

for row in records:
  cpu_temp_list.append(row[1])
  time_list.append(row[2])

# declare date formatter for plot
myFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M')

# generate plot
mpl.use('Agg')


plt.plot(time_list, cpu_temp_list, 'b-')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('CPU Temperature [°C]')
plt.title('CPU Temperature evolution over the last 48 hours')
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)

# save plot
plt.savefig('cpu_temp.png')
```

I get the following error :

```
Error writing cpu temp to mariaDB: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CPU_temp.py", line 45, in <module>
    for row in records:
NameError: name 'records' is not defined
```

EDIT:
I added a print(sql, args) before the error, here's the console print

```
insert into CPU_TEMP_TABLE (CPU_TEMP, CAMERA_TEMP) values (%s, %s) (64.27, 58.2)
```

EDIT 2:  added the rest of the code as some of you mentioned that error warning where displayed outside the shown code

EDIT 3: restarted from 0 and now it works... I cannot delete this post unfortunately

Comment: I checked and when I run the command directly inside mariaDB it works. There seems to be some issues with spaces or invisible characters in the string...

Comment: Try args = (cpu_temp, float(cam_temp))

Comment: @Sujay I tried, here's the result:
insert into CPU_TEMP_TABLE (CPU_TEMP, CAMERA_TEMP) values (%s, %s) (65.731, 58.2)
Error writing cpu temp to mariaDB: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CPU_temp.py", line 46, in <module>
    for row in records:
NameError: name 'records' is not defined

Comment: ("insert into CPU_TEMP_TABLE values (%s, %s)", (65.731, 58.2)) try

Comment: @Sujay
Error writing cpu temp to mariaDB: 1136 (21S01): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CPU_temp.py", line 47, in <module>
    for row in records:
NameError: name 'records' is not defined

Comment: There is no `for row in records` in the code in the question, yet it appears in the traceback.  Please ensure that the code in the question matches that which is reporting an error.

Comment: @snakecharmerb I guess it's another error below because the script couldn't read the database as it catches an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this query:

```sql
select *
from CPU_TEMP_TABLE 
where CPU_TEMP_TABLE.CREATED > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

The `DATE_SUB` function's parentheses are not closed.  The fix is to add the closing parenthesis:

```sql
select * 
from CPU_TEMP_TABLE 
where CPU_TEMP_TABLE.CREATED > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

It's unfortunate that the error message is so inscrutable...

Comment: Usually I'd vote to close as a typo, but the error message is so unhelpful that an answer is useful, I think.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put arguments into a tuple:

```
sql = "insert into CPU_TEMP_TABLE (CPU_TEMP, CAMERA_TEMP) values (%s, %s)"
args = (cpu_temp, float(cam_temp),)
cursor.execute(sql,args)
```

Or to construct a string in-place:

```
sql = "insert into CPU_TEMP_TABLE (CPU_TEMP, CAMERA_TEMP)
    values (%s, %s)" % (cpu_temp, float(cam_temp),)
cursor.execute(sql)
```

Comment: I tried the both ones and still got :

Error writing cpu temp to mariaDB: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CPU_temp.py", line 46, in <module>
    for row in records:
NameError: name 'records' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote everything from scratch and defined 2 distinct cursor and it somewhat worked.

Thanks for your help

Here's the working code:

```
from gpiozero import CPUTemperature
from time import sleep, strftime, time
import mysql.connector as mariadb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import datetime
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

# get CPU temperature in Celsius
cpu = CPUTemperature()
cpu_temp = cpu.temperature

# get Camera temperature in Celsius
tempfile = open("/home/pi/allsky/temperature.txt","r")
cam_temp = tempfile.read().rstrip()

# make a new mariaDB entry and retrieve old values
try:
   mariadb_connection = mariadb.connect(user='pi',password='...',database='cpu_tempDB')
   cursor1 = mariadb_connection.cursor()
   sql1 = "insert into CPU_TEMP_TABLE (CPU_TEMP, CAMERA_TEMP) values (%s, %s)"
   args = (cpu_temp, float(cam_temp))
   cursor1.execute(sql1,args)
   mariadb_connection.commit()

   cursor2 = mariadb_connection.cursor()
   sql2 = "select * from CPU_TEMP_TABLE where CREATED > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 DAY)"
   cursor2.execute(sql2)
   records = cursor2.fetchall()
except mariadb.Error as e:
   print("Error mariaDB:",e)
finally:
   mariadb_connection.close()
   cursor1.close()
   cursor2.close()
# store data in lists
time_list = []
cpu_temp_list = []
cam_temp_list = []

for row in records:
  cpu_temp_list.append(row[1])
  time_list.append(row[2])
  cam_temp_list.append(row[3])

# declare date formatter for plot
myFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M')

# generate plot
mpl.use('Agg')


plt.plot(time_list, cpu_temp_list, 'b-')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('CPU Temperature [°C]')
plt.title('CPU Temperature evolution over the last 48 hours')
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)

# save plot
plt.savefig('cpu_temp.png')
```